# Can I activate three 3GS iPhones if i set them all back to factory settings using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, iphone, sim

I was wondering if I have 3 3GS iPhones and they are all locked and I set them back to factory settings using iTunes, if I could activate them and just activate using one SIM card and then use them just with WiFi with out the SIM card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you said yourself you need a simcard to activate them. But afterwards you can use them "just Wi-Fi" without any problem. Sorry I can't write any longer answer, this is just as it is.

Comment: yes but can u activate more then one iphone with just one sim card

Comment: Yes. You can pull it out afterwards.